# Run GOLANG in Docker image FROM Terraform

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, terraform

My understanding is that the Terraform Docker image is from a Go (Golang) base image. I'm trying to build my own image using the Terraform image as a base, so I can run some custom Go commands before running my Terraform. However when I try to run Go it is not found.

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:1.1.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
COPY someotherterraformfiles.tf ./

RUN echo $(ls)

RUN go mod download
```

Error log...

```
Step 5/6 : RUN echo $(ls)
 ---> Running in a4333944d871
go.mod go.sum
Removing intermediate container a4333944d871
 ---> 173d8ba93215
Step 6/6 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Running in 4943df7818c2
/bin/sh: go: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

How do I get my `go` commands to work?

Comment: Turns out the dockerfile on terraforms github project isn't representative of what is distributed on dockerhub, the former is golang, the later linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base image, `hashicorp/terraform:1.1.3` is built on Alpine Linux, without Go installed.

The solution is to install Go before using it. This can be accomplished with adding `RUN apk add go` to a line above where the `go` CLI tool is used.

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:1.1.3

RUN apk add go

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
COPY someotherterraformfiles.tf ./

RUN echo $(ls)

RUN go mod download
```

Comment: Additionally, if you're trying to put a built executable into your image instead of building in the image, look into Docker multi-stage builds. By doing this, you could avoid installing Go in the image produced by your `Dockerfile`. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Maaaaan i really thought the base image was GO :o thanks you've saved me hours of head scratching.

Comment: This confuses me. 100% not disagreeing, just want to understand. Doesn't the [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/dockerfile) show it being built from `golang:alpine`?

Comment: A good way to check is to `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=sh hashicorp/terraform:1.1.3`, then run commands to see what's installed. Also `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: @theherk I'll report that as being incorrect.

Comment: Here's a quick summary: the Docker image Terraform puts on Docker Hub actually contains a bit of closed source code that isn't in their GitHub project's `Dockerfile`. Also they have an old version of their `Dockerfile` uploaded to Docker Hub. GitHub issue I made: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30368